# angular 4 click button function is not fired

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, ionic-framework, input

I am trying to do a check if a text input is empty or not in angular 4. I am not using forms for this. It's just an input field. When I execute the addLocaton function in the button below the check needs to happen.

> my input field

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Town, Province or City" name="newPlace" [(ngModel)]="newPlace" id="empty"></ion-input>

<button ion-button block type="submit" (click)="addLocation()">ADD AND SAVE MORE LOCATIONS</button>
```

> ts file

```
  addLocation(){
     if( document.getElementById('empty').value === '' ){
          alert('empty');
     }
  }
```

Comment: Its unnecessary to make `document.getElementById` you can simply go for the model newPlace and check if its either '' or 'Enter a Town, Province or City'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way

change `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` as the suggestion from @edkeveked

```
 <button ion-button block type="button" (click)="addLocation(newPlace)">ADD AND SAVE MORE LOCATIONS</button>
```

But you could do this way for passing the model object via method  instead of using plain JavaScript code

```
addLocation(newPlace){
     if(newPlace === '' || newPlace === undefined ){
          alert('invalid');
     }
  }
```

or use the two way binding

`(click)="addLocation()"`

and ts could be

```
addLocation(){
         if(this.newPlace === '' || this.newPlace === undefined ){
               alert('invalid');
         }
      }
```

Comment: newPlace was returning undefined, so I needed to also check if === undefined

Comment: @eohdev exactly. first time the object is undefined . because you didn't assign empty value  in `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 2):

Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

> With the type `button` the button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur whereas with the type `submit` it tries to make a form submit action. 
>   To catch that action in angular, you need to use the event binding to `(ngSubmit)`.

Since you're not using form, to handle your click action, here is the way to go.

```
<button ion-button block type="button" (click)="addLocation()">ADD AND SAVE MORE LOCATIONS</button>
```

Comment: solution was to do this `addLocation(){

    if( (this.newPlace === '') || (this.newPlace === undefined) ){
      alert('empty');
    }
    else{
      //execute functionality
    }

  }`

Comment: Yes, you can use the two binding to check and in that case you will remove the `click` action.